# Using Keycloak as an External IDP with OIDC in WSO2 APIM throws Too many redirects on logout

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've configured WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 using Keycloak 18.0.0 as an External IDP with OIDC for SSO in WSO2 consoles (Publisher, Admin and Devportal).

I've followed [these instructions](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/sso/okta-as-an-external-idp-using-oidc/#using-okta-as-an-external-idp-with-oidc) from WSO2 APIM (that integrates with OKTA) to configure the same thing with Keycloak.

I've manage to login successfully on DevPortal, Admin and Publisher consoles.

The problem is when hitting logout in any of these consoles.

[image: Logout]

After clicking logout, I've receive the

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

on the browser.

On the browser the following are the requests sent (suppress token for easier reading).

1. https://api.mycompany.com:9443/devportal/services/logout
2. https://api.mycompany.com:9443/oidc/logout?id_token_hint=eyJ4NXQiO...&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://api.mycompany.com:9443/devportal/services/auth/callback/logout
3. https://dev-apigw-2-pdun.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/realms/apim/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=e...&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.mycompany.com%3A9443%2Fcommonauth
4. https://api.mycompany.com:9443/commonauth?state=112132c3-ed35-4235-a451-8c5ef3b8dcbf%2COIDC

Requests 3 and 4 are then sent over and over again.

**The configuration on Keycloak**

I've create a new realm following this [url](https://dzone.com/articles/sso-wso2-api-manager-amp-keycloak).

I've activated:

- Standard Flow
- Implicit Flow Enabled
- Direct Access Grants Enabled
- Service Accounts Enabled
- Authorization Enabled

And configured:

- Valid Redirect URIs: *
- Web Origins: *

I've created role *subscriber*.
Also added a mappers:

- User Client Role -> role (token claim)
- username -> sub (token claim).

**WSO2 Carbon Console configurations**

Added a new Identity Provider. In this Identity Provider configured every URL to point to keycloak openid-connect URLs. On Callback URL: https://api.mycompany.com:9443/commonauth

Updated each Service Provider to use keycloak Identity Provider.

On *deployment.toml*, I've configured:

```
[server]
hostname = "$env{API_GATEWAY_SERVER_HOSTNAME}"
```

Where API_GATEWAY_SERVER_HOSTNAME = api.mycompany.com